# WPF: how to remove MenuItem border

Tags: wpf, xaml, menuitem

So i have simple `MenuItem`:

```
<ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu Name="cmCopy">
        <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource MenuItemDefaultStyle}" Header="Copy" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</ListView.ContextMenu>
```

And my `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemDefaultStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="4,0,6,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="7,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" ContentSource="Header" Width="40" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" HorizontalOffset="1" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" VerticalOffset="-1">

                        <Border BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" CanContentScroll="true" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Blue" TargetName="content"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And i really want s to remove this Border around my `MenuItem`.

And although i defined this:'

```
<Border BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
```

I can still see black `Border` brush.

**Update**

[image]

Comment: The `Border` in your `Style` is specified for a popup not the `MenuItem`.

Comment: So what should i change ?

Comment: In the Style `<Style x:Key="MenuItemDefaultStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}"> <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>` This should be above the `Template` tag.

Comment: No this not helped, i still can see the black border.

Comment: Is your Style being applied? What I mean is: does the text change to blue when mouse is over?

Comment: I don't see any border.. and the Text is blue on mouse over. What border do you mean? Can you post a picture?

Comment: Yes the text become Blue, i will post a picture soon

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Did you try setting `BorderThickness="0"` on the `ContextMenu`? Since you've posted a picture with only one item it's hard to tell, but it might just as well be the case that the border displayed around the whole menu rather than around particular items. As a side note, the `Border` you defined will only apply to nested items, but not top level items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mishka is right, it comes from ContextMenu style.  Here is a default Style, see my comment in it to get what you want.

```
<Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorLight">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorDark">#FF7381F9</Color>

<Color x:Key="DisabledControlLightColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="DisabledControlDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>

<Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>

<Color x:Key="ControlLightColor">White</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlMediumColor">#FF7381F9</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlDarkColor">#FF211AA9</Color>

<Color x:Key="ControlMouseOverColor">#FF3843C4</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlPressedColor">#FF211AA9</Color>


<Color x:Key="GlyphColor">#FF444444</Color>
<Color x:Key="GlyphMouseOver">sc#1, 0.004391443, 0.002428215, 0.242281124</Color>

<!--Border colors-->
<Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
<Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FF888888</Color>
<Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

<Color x:Key="PressedBorderLightColor">#FF888888</Color>
<Color x:Key="PressedBorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

<Color x:Key="DisabledBorderLightColor">#FFAAAAAA</Color>
<Color x:Key="DisabledBorderDarkColor">#FF888888</Color>

<Color x:Key="DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor">Black</Color>

<!--Control-specific resources.-->
<Color x:Key="HeaderTopColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="DatagridCurrentCellBorderColor">Black</Color>
<Color x:Key="SliderTrackDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>

<Color x:Key="NavButtonFrameColor">#FF3843C4</Color>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuPopupBrush"
                     EndPoint="0.5,1"
                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                Offset="0" />
  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                Offset="0.5" />
  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill"
                     StartPoint="0,0"
                     EndPoint="1,0">
  <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    <GradientStopCollection>
      <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                    Offset="0" />
      <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                    Offset="0.4" />
      <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                    Offset="0.6" />
      <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                    Offset="1" />
    </GradientStopCollection>
  </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="HasDropShadow"
          Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
        <Border x:Name="Border"
                Background="{StaticResource MenuPopupBrush}"
                BorderThickness="1">
          <Border.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BorderMediumColor}" /><!-- Set this brush to transparent -->
          </Border.BorderBrush>
          <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                      KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow"
                   Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border"
                    Property="Padding"
                    Value="0,3,0,3" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border"
                    Property="CornerRadius"
                    Value="4" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Template is not the only one  MenuItem receives.

MenuItem has a couple of Templates according to it's role.

It can be a leaf. It can be a Parent with children. It can be a parent without children.

As you can see here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/menu-styles-and-templates

You will need to modify all of them in order to achieve this.